# Designing interface to accommodate physical devices with different number & layout of ports

Tags: layout, checkboxes, physical, device, networks

The following device is a network switch.

This particular model contains 24 ports, arranged into 2 rows with 12 ports on each.

There exists hundreds of models of switches, each with different number & physical arrangement of ports.

[image]

I need to design a web interface where the user can choose to select multiple ports (& assign values to them in another part). This is what I have now for the port selection:

[image]

The problem I am facing is: **I don't want the user to think that the UI represents the physical layout of ports on the actual device (because it may not always be the case)**

How should I design the UI for this?

- Building a customized UI for each individual model is out of the question. The only thing that can be easily done would be the number of ports, not the physical layout.
- I could put a message on the UI explaining that the checkboxes don't reflect the actual arrangement, but I'd prefer the solution to be visual.
- It doesn't necessarily have to be checkboxes. It just has to be a way to select none or multiple ports

Answer (score 1):

Since you're worried about users making incorrect assumptions, it may be better to abstract away the physical layout entirely, and instead use something like a multiselect:

[image: React-Select.js style multiselect showing no ports selected in one state, and ports 1 and 3 selected in the other]